# How to add (sub)-domains to apache/ISPConfig2?

Tags: php, apache

I am working on a PHP-script to conventiently clone an existing CMS-Installation. Basically it all works fine, but the next thing I wanted to do is to auto-configure the (sub)domain for the new site in apache/ispconfig 2. I know ispconfig 3 would be better with its remoting capabilities, but unfortunately that is currently not an option because „*ISPConfig 3 is the next generation of the ISPConfig control panel, rewritten from scratch to support virtual users and multiple servers. ISPConfig 3 **can not be used to Update** a ISPConfig 2 installation*.“

Any chance to do this with v2???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that "remoting" which is available with ispconfig 3, is available for 2 also as an addon. Download and more info here: http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-2/remoting-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Just append the Apache  info to your httpd.conf like so:

```
$data = 
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.example.com
ServerName host.example.com
ErrorLog logs/host.example.com-error_log
TransferLog logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
;

file_put_contents('/path/to/filename', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Of course you'll still need to find a way to update your DNS with the new subdomain.

Comment: Thanks - your answer applies to apache only, but when ISPConfig is used there's a better solution available...

Comment: Are you asking me if there is a better solution or telling me?

Comment: Just telling that I finally found the answer myelf, using the remoting framework, as indicated below. (I had explicitely asked about doing this in a ISPCOnfig-Environment...)